# Logback logs into a previously created log file

Tags: linux, weblogic, logback

I have a logback.xml file in which a rotation is defined:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${user.dir}/servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/XYX.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.dir}/servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/XYX.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %-3.-3level %replace(%replace(%-28.-28thread){'ExecuteThread: ','th='}){'ACTIVE','A'} | [%X{facadeType} - %X{processId}] | %logger{10} [%file:%line] --> %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

```
<root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

I think the syntax is good here, because it works well, so to speak. The problem is that sometimes the logback start logging to a completely random file, a previously created file.

For example: it is 23.08.2023 today, and at 11:03 it started logging to the log file created on 10.08.2023, and at 16:04 it resumed logging to the right place. Or see the framed parts in the picture below:

[image]

Sometimes it logs to the wrong place for hours, it doesn't happen very often, but I don't see any correlation between the occurrences, it seems completely random.

- I checked the logback relase notes to see if there was an update or bug fix on this topic, but I couldn't find one.
- Syntax check, but no errors found.
- Checking and updating the version of installed applications running on server, mainly kernel, device mapper, etc, but no results, no improvement.
- Search for correlations between occurrences, but no results.
- Checking the last lines of log files where the log is interrupted, but no correlation there either.
- No errors in cron, crontab logs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a logback issue, pretty similar to

https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-53

Not sure which version you are using, but you'd better jump to the latest one.

Comment: I am using 1.2.3 version. I can try to jump on the latest one, but I'm not sure if it's going to fix it, because I had the same problem with previous versions too.